# ID Badge Access System for Building with Active Directory Integration

Tags: active-directory

I hope this is the right place for this question. So, we're looking into setting up a building access that uses badges or cards of some kind. I wanted to ask the users on here if they've had to do such setups and/or if they have recommendations?

Is there maybe a system that integrates with Active Directory? I know one of the things our managers want to do is to be able to run reports on when people are entering the buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of product, forget about which product to get and focus on who will support it. **You need to get recommendations for installers, not products.** Ask other people in your building. Ask other companies you do business with. Ask the property management companies in your area who they use. Pick someone that has been in business for a while and can guarantee response times for problems. All of the worthwhile access control products (and good installers will only sell the worthwhile ones) have the reporting you need.

Comment: +1 for finding a good installer / support company. When this beast breaks (and you know it will one day) you want to know the installer will be there helping you fix it so people can get into the building!

Answer (score 1):

Such systems do exist, and like all [physical] security products, they're primitive in functionality and way overpriced for what they do.  This isn't a site for product recommendations, but most of the systems these days pipe data to a SQL database on a computer somewhere, and you can certainly integrate that with LDAP/AD.

I'd search on `Building Door Access Control` or `Physical Door Access Control` in a search engine to get a quick lay of the land as to options.  There are an absolute slew of them, but you're probably (maybe?) looking at a keypads or badge readers for existing doors, to help narrow your search a bit.